# Import file in stylus with checking for variable

Tags: stylus

```
    style_connection($connect) {
      if $connect==true {
        {block}
      }
    }

    +style_connection($bs-normalize)
    @import "normalize"
```

I made mixin, which checks for  a variable and then imports the file. But there's a problem - importing file runs first, then there is a check for the presence of a variable. I want if the variable is not defined, the importing file will not run.

Answer (score 0):

> I want if the variable is not defined, the importing file will not run.

Well, as I can see, your code works exactly like this.

I've made some examples:

```
style_connection($connect) {
  if $connect==true {
    {block}
  }
}

+style_connection(true) {
  @import "test"
}
```

`test.styl`

```
body
  color red
```

And:

```
style_connection($connect) {
  if $connect==true {
    {block}
  }
}

+style_connection($undef-var) {
  @import "test"
}
```

The first example yields to:

```
  body {
    color: #f00;
  }
```

The second outputs an empty file (doesn't import anything).

Comment: Try to make a mistake in the file 'test'. Then compilation will be unsuccessful, regardless of value of the variable $ connect.  I want if the variable is not defined,  compilation will be successful.